# Mass URL parameter cleanup from txt file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have file with a list of URLs like this:

```
www.dell.com/any=abc&anyone=bcd
www.google.co.in 
www.yahoo.com/abc=fgh
```

I want to clean them up as they show only data up to equal sign. For example the above should become:

```
www.dell.com/any=
www.dell.com/any=abc&anyone=
www.google.co.in 
www.yahoo.com/abc=
```

Any script suggestions for cleanup of code like this in python or bash, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to apply the following transformations:

- If the line doesn't contain `=`, do nothing
- If the line contains a single `=`, then delete everything after the `=`
- If the line contains multiple `=`, then perform the previous step repeatedly until there is none, printing the intermediary results at each step

Here's one way to do that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read line; do
    if [[ "$line" == *=* ]]; then
        while [[ "$line" == *=* ]]; do
            line=${line%=*}
            echo $line=
        done
    else
        echo $line
    fi
done
```

If you save this in a file `script.sh`, you can use it like this:

```
./script.sh < input.txt
```

This will produce the output you asked in your question.

Comment: this works fine ,, thanks ,,, just one addition if you can ,,,, output this data to txt file in script e.g--     echo data >> output.txt  ,,, something like this.

Comment: @user7423959 Not sure what you mean. You could run as `./script.sh < input.txt > output.txt`, or if you want to make the saving part of the script, then you could redirect the loop, by changing the `done` statement to `done > output.txt`